# Use stream provider inside Stateful Widget to get data for single firestore document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have specific firestore document and I want get the value of field of that document updated every second because the field represent the number of notifications of user, But when I Looking for stream provider first time I was read we can't use it inside Stateful widget.

My Document Path
[image]

**My home page code:**

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final User me;

  Home({
    Key key,
    this.me,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  int numberOfNotifications;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: GlobalUniversal.whiteBG,
      body: Center(
        child: Text(numberOfNotifications.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**db.dart**

```
class DatabaseService {
  final Firestore db = Firestore.instance;

  Future<UserNotification> getUserNotification(String doc) async {
    var snap = await db.collection(NOTIFICATIONS_USERS_ONE_COLLECTION).document(doc).get();
    return UserNotification.fromMap(snap.data);
  }

  Stream<UserNotification> streamUserNotifications(String doc){
    return db.collection(NOTIFICATIONS_USERS_ONE_COLLECTION).document(doc).snapshots().map((snap) => UserNotification.fromMap(snap.data));
  }
}
```

user.dart

```
class UserNotification {
      int userNotifications;
      UserNotification({this.userNotifications});
    
      factory UserNotification.fromMap(Map data) {
        return UserNotification(
          userNotifications: data[UN_READ_COUNTS_FIELD] ?? 0,
        );
      }
    }
```

but when I try call provider inside home page I got an error.
[image]

**error: The named parameter 'stream' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `.value` if you are instantiating your stream in your provider

```dart
StreamProvider<UserNofitication>(
  create: (BuildContext context) => db.streamUserNotification(widget.me.doc),
  child: Center(
    child: Text(numberOfNotifications.toString()),
  ),
),
```

If `db.streamUserNotification(widget.me.doc)` is already an instance of stream, you can use `StreamProvider.value` and the named parameter is `value` and not `stream` :

```dart
StreamProvider<UserNofitication>.value(
  value: db.streamUserNotification(widget.me.doc),
  child: Center(
    child: Text(numberOfNotifications.toString()),
  ),
),
```

---

EDIT

to use the stream you can use the `builder` of the `StreamProvider` to read the `context`

```dart
StreamProvider<UserNofitication>(
  create: (BuildContext context) => db.streamUserNotification(widget.me.doc),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    numberOfNotifications = context.watch<UserNotification>()?.userNotifications ?? 0;
    return Center(
      child: Text(numberOfNotifications.toString()),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: Sorry the parameter should be `create` and not `stream`, I'm updating my answer

Comment: When I switched to create there are error showing , can you edit your code to what you mean exactly with display the value in text

Comment: `create` should be a function that returns a stream, I already updated my answer accordingly, I don't know if you saw it. What is the error you get ?

Comment: error: The argument type 'Stream<UserNotification> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<UserNotification> Function(BuildContext)'.

Comment: My bad, you should just add the `context` argument in the function `create: (BuildContext context => db.streamUserNotification(widget.me.doc),` then

Comment: the error is gone, to get the value and set it to "numberOfNotifications" and show it what should I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228635/discussion-between-valentin-vignal-and-abdullrahman-wasfi).